# how to rename sheet name different from file name

Tags: excel, vba

I have some vba to create a new workbook with a sheet name of "SheetName", data is then transferred to the new sheet and savedas with a file name and saved as CSV format
The file name is copying over the sheet name I've declared earlier which i do not want.

```
Private Sub TransferData()

'---Submit Button Code - Transfers data to new workbook, renames and saves to folder.

Dim SheetName As String
Dim SavePath As String
Dim FileName As String
SheetName = "IATData"
SavePath = "savedfolderpath"
FileName = IAT.SaveDateBox.Value & IAT.SaveTimeBox.Value & IAT.SaveAssessorBRIDBox & IAT.BRIDBox


'Create new workbook for saved CSV
With Application
    .SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1
    .Workbooks.Add
    .Sheets(1).Name = SheetName
End With

'Turn off Auto-Calculate
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Turn off Alert Displays
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Determine Empty Row
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer the data to the master
'---Front Page---
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = IAT.BRIDBox.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = IAT.AgentNameBox.Value

'Save new workbook etc.
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=SavePath & FileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Workbooks("IAT Form.xlsm").Activate
MsgBox "Details sent to data folder under: " & FileName

End Sub
```

Would expect the new workbook to have a sheet name "IATData" and the file name to be made up of the cell reference noted above, but the worksheet keeps being named as the filename as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "sheet name" in a CSV: it's a plain-text file format and the sheet name always shows as the filename.

CSV has nothing other than data - there's no place for Excel to put a sheet name (in fact there's not even a "sheet" in a CSV). If you open your CSV in notepad you can see what I mean.

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you save the new workbook as ***.CSV***, the sheetname is lost.  The file is just a text csv file.  When this .csv is re-opened by Excel, the sheetname will default to the filename.